# Changing the value of model defined in rootScope before leaving the current scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can we change the value of model defined in `$rootScope` before leaving the current scope in AngulrJS.

for example if the value of `$rootScope.isPresent = true` in

../testMe url. And if we hit another url with the same `$rootScope`

then how can we change the value of `$rootScope.isPresent` variable before displaying the view and initialing controller of new URL.

Comment: Maybe you should try $locationChangeStart event which is broadcasted before a URL will change. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: are you using ui-router ? if yes, use $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ... )

Comment: Is is possible to add common method which will always trigger when there is a change in URL with corresponding rootScope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a block of code before changing states that lead to changing scopes, you can use:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function()
{
// your code goes here
});
```

AngularJS automatically fires a $destroy event when it tries to destroy the scope, which lets your code execute before leaving this state.